Splitting up a date with computed?
I've simplified my example but it is still not working...
So, I have a model which is a full date (2000-01-01)
const model = defineModel({
    type: String,
});

I need to split this up into year, month day. So if we just concentrate on day for now....
const day = computed({
    get() {
        return model.value.split('-')[2];
    },
    set(newValue) {
        model.value = `${year.value}-${month.value}-${newValue.padStart(2, 0)}`;
    },
});

    <input v-model="day"/>

When getting day it works, taking the value from the full date, the issue occurs with the setter. I can type in a very large number, and the leading zero will always be there.
How can I ensure that only 2 digits can be entered for day, and if it's 9 or below, a leading zero is added?

padStart has no mechanism to remove leading zeroes, so once you type in a single number and a 0 is added, that 0 will remain even if you add more numbers.  It's more useful to use padStart with static values, like if you pasted "20" rather than typing "2" then "0".  An alternative solution would be to use an if statement where if newValue <= 9, prepend a 0, else use newValue

I'm not sure about this case, but you probably need to normalize a value, i.e. convert it back to number, String(parseInt(newValue)).padStart(2, 0)

The simple answer to your question is to simply use slice(-2) to always take the last two digits of the day string.

A more thorough answer though would require answers to how you handle invalid values, or how you want to handle inputs that would create an invalid value. Essentially, you need to validate that the input conforms to your requirements, and if not, to either transform it into a valid value or give the user a validation error/warning that the input value is invalid.
This means that you need to handle several different scenarios. Assuming in each of the following cases that the caret is at the end of the input and selection is empty:

Current input value is 01 and the user presses 1

You current get 011. What you want to do is take the last two digits so simply call slice(-2) on the value.


Current input value is 11 and the user presses 3. What do you do?

Set the value to 3 because 113 is invalid?
Set the value to 13 pushing out the first 1?
Leaving the invalid number and marking the field with a warning (possibly only once focus leaves the field)?


Current input value is 9 and user presses 0. What do you do?

Set the value to 90?
Set the value to 0?
Set it to the nearest valid number (end of month, so 28/29/30/31)?
Set it to the lowest valid number (i.e. 1)?
Clculate the change and update the month and year fields to the new date? (e.g. 2000-01-01 + 89 days would be 2000-03-30)



There are more edge cases, like when the caret is at the start of the input, or the middle. The implementation depends on the UX that you want to create.
